# USB-C to USB-C from laptop to dock won’t work on external monitors, but directly plugging HDMI cord into screen works

Tags: external-display, docking-station, dock

Okay the headline pretty much sums it up, but I have two external monitors hooked up to a dock. When I plug in the usb-c to usb-c into my laptop it works fine and appears on both external monitors. However, with another computer (we’ll call it computer 2) I have it won’t work. The monitor is black. When I plug one monitor into computer 2 with an HDMI cable it streams fine.

- HP Probook X360 g7
- Dock: Targus (model: Dock190),
- Monitors: Lenovo ThinkVision (model: F13268QP1).

Side bar: i have my wireless mouse plugged into the dock and that works fine.

I’m out of ideas here, any thoughts?

Comment: Please provide more specifics.  WAY more specifics so we can all sort this one out.  There are many reasons floating through my head and I am BY FAR not the smartest person in the room.  Please give us more to contemplate.

Comment: Thanks for commenti! I’d love to. I’m not very adept at this stuff so after a lot of googling and IT support calls I figured I’d try here, but I don’t know what specifics to give. When I connect directly to the laptop it works, but I can not get anything on the monitors when I connect to the docking station. And yet, it’s clearly working because the wireless mouse usb works when plugged into the dock, so I imagine it’s a laptop issue. I’ve changed the refresh rate and that is what finally enabled the hdmi plug to work. 
Could you tell me what other information I could provide that might help?

Comment: Specifics about hardware.  What brand/model of laptop. "Docking station"? what models thinger is that?  As much as you can down to the last detail of gfx included (laptops often vary by price even if same model), etc.  I am not saying someone here will fix this for you but the only chance we have requires more information.  There are some REALLY SMART people here just waiting to help you.  Simply follow the rules and show respect (not to me) and someone will do their best.

Comment: Ahh thank you for the clarification! I appreciate it. So, the laptop is an HP Probook X360 g7, the dock is a Targus (model: Dock190), and the monitors are Lenovo ThinkVision (model: F13268QP1). I scanned through some of the threads on here and it seems like there are a lot of brilliant people that know infinitely more than I do lol thanks again!

Comment: USB-C is a plug type, not a protocol spec [which makes it, imnsho, the worst plug ever for consumer confusion]. Not all USB-C ports are equal. HP says it has one port with PD & DP, the other is charging only. Try the other port. https://support.hp.com/gb-en/document/c06646120#AbT7

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I really appreciate it. It ended up being a driver issue, I had to go on the dock company website and find the appropriate driver installation. Took a couple different downloads to find the right one but it’s working perfectly now thankfully. I really appreciate all the input!